# Loop without do, even though i have a do

Tags: excel, loops, powerpoint, vba

My code is below. Essentially each powerpoint table should only hold 32 rows worth of excel data (and the heading row), so i want the slide number to increase every 32 rows and for excel to cycle through the rows to the copy the data across. happy to try and explain further if that doesn't make sense but wanted to give some form of context to my issue.

As far as i can see i have a do until, loop, if and end if. yet i'm getting the 'Loop without do' error and i'm at a loss as to why.

n = 2

```
Do Until n = lrow

 Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Table 3")

    With oPPTShape.Table
           If n Mod 33 <> 0 Then

                   .Cell(n, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 1).Text
                   .Cell(n, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 2).Text
                   .Cell(n, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 3).Text
                   .Cell(n, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 4).Text
                   .Cell(n, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 5).Text

                n = n + 1
           Else
           SlideNum = SlideNum + 1
                   .Cell(n, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 1).Text
                   .Cell(n, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 2).Text
                   .Cell(n, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 3).Text
                   .Cell(n, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 4).Text
                   .Cell(n, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 5).Text
                n = n + 1
          End If

Loop
```

many thanks!

Comment: sorry amended, using excel vba to create a power point presentation automatically.

Comment: You are missing an `End With`.

Comment: can't believe i missed that will give it a try! thanks, was too busy focusing on the end if, rather than end with!

Comment: Would help if it said something helpful like "missing end with"!

Comment: Can't seem to get this to do what i want it to anyway. trying to populate powerpoint table with excel data, but there is a limit of 32 rows of data per table, i want it to then go onto the next slide, and fill those, until the last row of excel data. Anyone have any ideas please!? really at a loss and will have to do it another way otherwise

Comment: Off top of head, turn your existing code into a subroutine that takes the table object, the excel object and the next excel row to be used as parms.  Your main routine would add a slide, add a table and keep track of what row you're on, passing the needed info off to the subroutine to do the work of populating the table.

Comment: You seem to be using n for both the excel row and the PPT table row.  But the PPT table row has to be tween 2 (for header row ) and 33 for the data rows, while the excel row continues from 2 to last row number.  Where does the excel row data start?  You have n-3 , so when n=2 then excel data row is 5?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about your data set up and how your slides look, but if the shape is named Table 3 on each slide and there are 33 total rows in your Table #, (header  + 32 rows) and your data starts on row 5 in your excel sheet, then this may work.  Your cell reference for the Excel sheet may need to be more exact like, Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(n+3,1).text
Here is some untested code to get you on your way.

```
N= 2
Do Until n = lrow
  Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Table 3")
    With oPPTShape.Table
      if n < 34 then    'this is because for the first slide n< 34 there is no 0 or 1 for n mod 33
           If n Mod 33 <> 0 Then
                   .Cell(n, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 1).Text
                   .Cell(n, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 2).Text
                   .Cell(n, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 3).Text
                   .Cell(n, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 4).Text
                   .Cell(n, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 5).Text
                n = n + 1
           Else  ' for when n = 33 
                   .Cell(n, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 1).Text
                   .Cell(n, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 2).Text
                   .Cell(n, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 3).Text
                   .Cell(n, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 4).Text
                   .Cell(n, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 5).Text
                n = n + 1
          End If
           SlideNum = SlideNum + 1
   Else     ' when n > 33
    x = n mod 33
           If n Mod 33 <> 0 Then

                   .Cell(x + 1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 1).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 2).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 3).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 4).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 5).Text

                n = n + 1
           Else  ' for when n = 66 or 99, etc.... start of next slide
              SlideNum = SlideNum + 1
                   .Cell(x + 1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 1).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 2).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 3).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 4).Text
                   .Cell(x + 1, , 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(n + 3, 5).Text
          End If
  End If ' for checking n<34
End With
Loop
```